# How to change icon of an app through Terminal

Tags: macos, command-line, icon, automation

I want to customize my app icons, but there's a lot of them, and I don't want to be tedious and go through the whole Get Info process over and over again.

Is there any way to write a program, preferably in Terminal using the command line, that will change the icon of an app?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to easily change the icon of the applications its best to use an application like [liteicon](https://freemacsoft.net/liteicon/) You can just drag and drop the icon you want to use.